# Young Tableaux Generalizing

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, young-tableaux

The entries in an array include all the digits from 1 through 9, arranged so that the entries in every row and column are in increasing order. How many such arrays are there? (2010 AMC12 B)

The answer is 42. Isn't there a specific process that answers this, such as Involution numbers? In other words, is there a specific list of numbers like Catalan numbers that can solve this or a formula, or is there a solution that involves Involution/telephone numbers?

What if the question was generalized to digits to $n^2$ in an $n \times n$ standard Young Tableaux? How can that be easily solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of standard Young tableaux of a given shape is given by the hook-length formula, see the formula for $\dim \pi_\lambda$ and the image in the link below:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook-length_formula#Dimension_of_a_representation

In particular, the number of standard Young tableaux of a $n\times n$ square is given by $$\frac{(n^2)!}{\frac{n!(n+1)!\dots (2n-1)!}{0!1!\dots(n-1)!}}=\frac{(n^2)!}{\prod_{k=1}^{2n-1}k^{\min(k,2n-k)}}.$$

Compare your $n=3$ case: $$\frac{9\cdot 8\cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2 \cdot 1}{1\cdot2^2\cdot 3^3\cdot 4^2\cdot 5}=7 \cdot 6 =42.$$

Comment: Very nice! Great help

Comment: But I don't understand the "dimension." What is meant by this and how does it correlate to the number of different young tableaux?

Comment: @Yadnarav3 The irreducible representations of the symmetric group happen to have (vector space) bases that are indexed by Young tableaux of a given shape. Therefore, counting the Young tableaux means that you are calculating the dimension of a particular representation. The formula really does exactly the enumeration you want, but it also has an algebraic meaning. If you are interested, you can, for example, read "The Symmetric group" by Sagan or "Young tableaux" by Fulton.