# Is this a well-known combinatorics problem?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that the numbers from $1$ to $n^2$ are arranged to form an $n$ by $n$ array consisting of $n$ rows and $n$ columns such that the numbers in each row (from left to right) and each columns (from top to bottom) are in increasing order. What are the total number of ways to arrange the numbers?

For instance, for $n=2$, there are two possibilities:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\text{ and }
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3\\
2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Some analysis, which I have done. If the entry in the $j^{th}$ and $k^{th}$ column is denoted as $a_{jk}$, it is not hard to construct a bound for $a_{jk}$. For instance, $$jk \leq a_{jk} \leq n^2+1-(n-j+1)(n-k+1)$$
Hence, number of possibilities for $a_{jk}$ is bounded by $$(n^2+1-(n-j+1)(n-k+1)) -jk+1 = (k+j-2)n - 2jk+j+k+1$$
Hence, the total number of possibilities is bounded by
$$\prod_{j=1}^n\prod_{k=1}^n \left((k+j-2)n - 2jk+j+k+1 \right)$$ We could probably get an asymptotic based on what I have obtained above.

Can this be simplified further? or in fact can an exact answer be obtained?

Comment: Yes, that is called a Young tableau (a particular case). [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau]

Comment: But the OP only wants the young tableaux with square shape.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560551/young-tableaux-generalizing/620345

Answer (score 0):

@user119256 Ok. Thanks. So if I understand it correctly, the answer is $$\dfrac{(n^2)!}{(2n-1)(2n-2)^2(2n-3)^3 \cdots (2n-(n-1))^{n-1}(2n-n)^n (2n-(n+1))^{n-1} \cdots 3^3 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 1^1}$$